# Redirect 301 adicionando muitas "/"s no final

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, htaccess

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema com a combinação de mais de um `.htaccess` em meu projeto.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
siteprincipal.com.br (não é WordPress)
```

e dentro um subdominio com um outro site em WordPress

```
site2.siteprincipal.com.br
```

o site2 está dentro de um diretório no `public_html`, onde o site principal roda

tenho dois `.htaccess` na seguinte estrutura

```
public_html (siteprincipal)
|--.htaccess
|--site2 (wordpress)
   |--.htaccess
```

quando faço um `redirect` de uma url do `siteprincipal` para o `site2`, como por exemplo

```
Redirect 301 /paginainterna/ http://site2.siteprincipal.com.br/paginainterna
```

o resultado final é

```
http://site2.siteprincipal.com.br/paginainterna////////////////
```

o que resulta em um redirect incorreto.

o conteúdo `.htaccess` do `siteprincipal` é

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /paginainterna/ http://site2.siteprincipal.com.br/paginainterna

#redirect sempre para www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

e o `.htaccess` do `site2` é o padrão do WordPress

```
# BEGIN WordPress
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

de que forma posso evitar que esse monte de "/" seja incluído, ou ainda o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse tipo de estrutura, o primeiro `.htaccess` gerencia tanto as chamadas para o dominio principal quanto para o subdomínio.

Note que as duas página possuem o mesmo endereço, por exemplo:

```
www.siteprincipal.com.br/page1
```

e

```
site2.siteprincipal.com.br/page1
```

o redirecionamento entrará em loop pois o primeiro `.htaccess` mandará para o subdomínio e tentará redirecionar novamente pois está baseado apenas no `%{REQUEST_URI}`.

por isso é importante não fazer um redirect utilizando

```
Redirect 301 /page1 http://site2.siteprincipal.com.br/page1
```

e sim

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.siteprincipal\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/page1$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://site2.siteprincipal.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

dessa forma garante-se que o redirect atinja apenas a chamada feita diretamente para o `siteprincipal` e não para o subdomínio.